# WCF endpoint is not being reached using jMeter 3.3

Tags: wcf, soap, jmeter

i'm using jMeter 3.3 and trying to ping my wcfservice.

Address: `http://localhost:88/MyService.svc`
Endpoint: `MyEndpoint`

I have created Jmeter http request

[image]

Server `name:localhost`
Port: `88`
Method: `Post`
Path : `/MyService.svc`

and filled in http header according to tutorials:
[image]

Content-Type: `text/xml`
SOAPAction: `http://localhost:88/MyService/MyEndpoint`

Problem is that my ednpoint is not being reached. The same data in soapUi or WcfTestClient works well. Did i miss something in JMeter configuration?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing couple of things

1. Your content type should specify charset so proper value is: text/xml; charset=utf-8
2. There is no body on your screenshot, so I'm not sure if it is filled. It it is not filled, you should take request body from WCF Test Client, extract body part and put it into Body Data tab.

For example, original envelope from WCF Test Client is like this:

```
    <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <s:Header>
         <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/IService1/DoWork</Action>
      </s:Header>
      <s:Body>
        <DoWork xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" />
      </s:Body>
    </s:Envelope>
```

Body for JMeter should not have Header part:

```
    <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <s:Body>
        <DoWork xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" />
      </s:Body>
    </s:Envelope>
```

In general Jmeter configuration should be as follows:

[image]
[image]

That should fix the problem.

P.S. View Results Tree is great for debugging

Answer (score 1):

Given you are able to run the request via SoapUI you should be able to capture it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

1. [Configure JMeter for recording](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#test_plan_building).

   - From JMeter main menu select `File -> Templates -> Recording` and click "Create"
     [image: JMeter Recording Template]
   - Open `Workbench -> HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder` then click "Start"
2. Configure SoapUI for recording

   - From SoapUI Main Menu select `File -> Preferences -> Proxy Settings` and click "Manual"
   - Use `localhost` as "Host" and `8888` as Port

     [image: SoapUI recording]
3. Run your request in SoapUI
4. JMeter will intercept the request and store it in form of [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler under `Test Plan -> Thread Group -> Recording Controller`. You should be able to successfully replay the request in JMeter.

Another option is [converting SoapUI XML to JMeter jmx using Taurus tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-convert-soapui-xml-jmeter-jmx)